# Javascript and PHP regex validation

Tags: php, javascript, regex, validation

I am making an form on my website but I have an problem with 2 regexs.
(I have an PHP regex and an JS regex because I read that javascript only is dangerous)

First is in PHP

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
                    if(strlen($name) < 2 || strlen($name) > 20 || preg_match('#[0-9]#',$name))
                    {   
                        echo '<p class="center"> je naam: <b> '.$name.' </b>  bevat cijfers en/of mag niet korter zijn dan 2 tekens en niet langer zijn dan 20 tekens. </p>';                   
                        echo '<p class="center"> <a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">Ga terug</a></p> ';
                    }
```

this preg_match give's an error if there are numbers in the name.
The question is I dont want that people have &^*#@ and that things in there name.

What is the correct regex for that.

Next is Javascript

```
function checkform ( form )
    {
        if (form.name.value == "") 
        {
            alert( "Please enter your name." );
            form.name.focus();
            return false ;
        }

        if (form.email.value == "")
        {
            alert( "Please enter your email address." );
            form.email.focus();
            return false ;
        }

        return true ;
    }
```

Here I want the same thing and validate that checks emptyness and length and no #$^&!

For email validate I need another regex but i search that one later.

Greeting Jochem

Please edit if you see mistakes.

**EDIT:**

var re and var regex are email regexs that i found.
But why wont they work kan someone give me an good answer with explination because i am not so good. :)

```
function checkform ( form )
    {
        var rex = /[^a-z]/i;
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
        var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

        if (regex.test(form.email.value))
        {
            alert( "Please enter your email address." );
            form.email.focus();
            return false ;
        }

        if (rex.test(form.name.value)) 
        {
            alert( "Please enter your name. no numbers or #$^& things allowed)." );
            form.name.focus();
            return false ;
        }

        return true ;
    }
```

Comment: I would like to recommend you use a JavaScript framework like jQuery and use the jQuery validate plugin. This will give you great client-side validation that has been tested on all browsers, etc. Especially when I come to specific validation like e.g. email, URL, (dutch) postcode and also gives additional regex possibilies and server-side captcha validation, etc: http://tinyurl.com/2e9cgj And demos: http://tinyurl.com/6ad8o9

Comment: Thank you. I will look this later, this is for a practice thingie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to accept letters, use `/[^a-z]/i`. You can use this regex in PHP and in JavaScript.

Comment: Your email regexes test if the email is *valid*, so you need to trigger the error when `!regex.test()`.